# Local data storage in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm making an app that will allow to learn/test knowledge based on answering lots of questions for certain categories an sub-categories. Now, I want to properly store my question data which consists of: question text, question image (optional), question category with several sub-categories, date, possible answers and which is the correct answer. I think **UserDefaults** is not appropriate since I'm going to have many questions more than 1000 and will be increasing. I want to store all data locally since I want to allow people learn anytime they want. Should I go for **CoreData** framework or is there any other, more suitable approach in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data would work great, however, it takes a while to get the hang of it with, you need to understand the entire stack before you begin writing and reading objects.

Personally, I think [Realm](https://realm.io/) is a better fit for your case because of how simple your app is. You can get your app up and running in 10 mins using Realm.

In your case you can create models similarly to how you would normally create models for your app, like this:

```
class Category: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
}

class SubCategory: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var category: Category
}

class Question: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var imageUrl: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var subCategory: SubCategory

    ....
}
```